# Whats the best way to avoid reloading videos when using the same source in different components or pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there an option in Javascript, React, or Next JS to optimize loading performance when using the same video resource in different components on different pages on the site (to avoid reloading)? Something like keeping the videos that have been loaded in Memory to not load them again if the layout changes. An example use case could be a full-width list view of multiple videos in one component and a grid overview in another.

```
const ComponentOne = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <video className="videoStyle01" autoPlay muted loop>
        // Using the same video src
        <source src="../videos/video_H264.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <div>Video title</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>Other Styling Elements and Description</div>
      <video className="videoStyle02" autoPlay muted loop>
        // Using the same video src
        <source src="../videos/video_H264.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try React Memo,

If your component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo then it boosts the performance

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: I know React Memo. Can you please be a bit more specific on how to implement it. Do you want me to wrap a variable `const sourceLinks = ["video1"]` into `useMemo` or does it have to be the whole `const videos = [<video src="video1" />]`tag to work. Or even the whole component?

Comment: If you create a react memo component  of only video then use it in different components

Comment: And this will work even if I `map` multiple of these `useMemo` components? Like `videos.map((src) => <UseMemoComponent src={src} />)` and then change pages.

Comment: No, because of this time src of the video changes because of the mapping of src which means the component render time video again loads, and if it"s the same src then it will work

Comment: So therefore you mean `React.memo()` and not `useMemo()` , am I right?

Comment: yes, use React.memo()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245515/discussion-between-meet-majevadiya-and-benjamink).